# Javascript event listeners not being added after following link

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am using a button to control a collapsible sidebar menu. On initial load, the button works fine. After following the link and inspecting the element, I can tell the event listener is not being added and the button stops working until I refresh the page. I am new to rails so I am not sure as to why this is the case. Any help is much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>BugSmacker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="page-container">
      <div id="content-wrap">
        <div class="bg-dark py-3">
          <h1 class="nav-title pl-2"> <span class="bug-title" >Bug</span> Smacker</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="py-3 second-nav">
          <button id="navbtn" class="btn nav-btn btn-lg fs-2">&#9776;</button>
        </div>
        <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar" data-open="false">
          <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
          <%= link_to 'Sign In', new_user_session_path %>
          <%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path %>
        </div>
        <div id="main" class="px-0 py-0">
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer id="footer" class="bg-dark pt-3">
        <a href="#" class="footer-link mx-2">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="footer-link mx-2">About</a>
        <a href="#" class="footer-link mx-2">Contact</a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks";
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage";
import "channels";

Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();
ActiveStorage.start();
require("jquery");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  function openNav() {
    const sidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");
    sidebar.dataset.open = "true";
    sidebar.style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    const sidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");
    sidebar.dataset.open = "false";
    sidebar.style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  }

  function toggleNav() {
    const sidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");
    const isOpen = sidebar.dataset.open;
    if (isOpen === "true") {
      closeNav();
    } else {
      openNav();
    }
  }

  var openBtn = document.getElementById("navbtn");
  openBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleNav, false);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change below.

```
# old
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

# new
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
```